# Adicionar valor de outro dataset caso encontre o mesmo nome com pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Boa tarde pessoal.

Tenho algo simples para fazer mais que não estou conseguindo resolver.

Tenho dois datasets **df_1** e **df_2**, que ambos tem uma coluna em comum *USUARIO* e **df_2** tem uma coluna a mais que é a *ID_AJUSTADO*.

Segue abaixo:

No **df_1.USUARIO** tenho:

```
USUARIO

VALMIR RODRIGUES PESSOA
VALMIR RODRIGUES PESSOA
ALIOMAR DE BARROS VIANA
PEDRO DE FREITAS PESSOA
```

No **df_2** tenho:

```
USUARIO | ID_AJUSTADO

VALMIR RODRIGUES PESSOA | 2918
CARLOS GUILHERME OLIVEIRA DE MELO | 7035
ALIOMAR DE BARROS VIANA | 209
EDRO DE FREITAS PESSOA  | 2512
EDRO DE FREITAS PESSOA  | 2512
```

Caso encontre o *USUARIO* de **df_1** em **df_2**, tenho que criar uma nova coluna **df_1['ID USUARIO AJUSTADO']** com a o valor da coluna *ID_AJUSTADO* do **df_2**

Caso eu não encontre, tenho que pegar o último valor de Indice e soma mais 1.

**Exemplo:**

O Usuário **VALMIR RODRIGUES PESSOA** está em **df_1** e **df_2**.
Então preciso pegar o seu *ID_AJUSTADO* em **df_2** e adicionar na nova coluna **df_1.ID_AJUSTADO**.

Então ficaria para este caso:

**df_1:**

```
USUARIO | ID_AJUSTADO

VALMIR RODRIGUES PESSOA | 2918
```

No meu código fiz assim:

```
ultimo_index = df_2['ID USUARIO AJUSTADO'].max()

df_1['ID USUARIO AJUSTADO'] = np.where(np.isin(df_1.USUARIO, df_2.USUARIO), df_2.ID_AJUSTADO, ultimo_index + 1)
```

Porém recebo o erro:

```
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (761,) (61222,) ()
```

Alguém poderia me ajudar ?

Caso não tenha ficado bem explicado, me avise por gentileza.

Comment: Um merge não resolveria?

Comment: Boa tarde, é verdade, porém quando estou utilizando, está retornando valores duplicados, saberia do porque ?

No meu dataset original, o df_1 é menor que df_2, então tenho que trazer apenas  a quantidade de linha do df_1. Código:



juntar = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on='USUARIO', how = 'left')

Comment: Veja se resolve assim: `df1=df1.merge(df2, on='USUARIO', how='left')`

Comment: Pior que eu tentei dessa forma também, por algum motivo ele duplica as linhas.

Answer (score 0):

Acho que isso aqui resolve seu problema:

`df_1_novo = df_1.merge(df_2, on='USUARIO', how='left')`

Comment: Pior que não, não sei do porque está repetindo valores.

Comment: Provavelmente porque seu df_1 tem valores repetidos.

Answer (score 0):

Fiz o merge e tirei os duplicados, depois fiz o merge de novo e deu certo.
Creio que o problema foi o um para muitos.

Obrigado pessoal.

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).